# Linear transformation and invertibality

Tags: linear-transformations

Let T be a linear transformation from a vector space V over reals into V such that T-T^2=I .showthat T is invertible.where I is unit matrix.

Comment: $$T(T-I)=(T-I)T=I$$

Comment: Is not it technically mixed, transformations and matrices?

Comment: @Vim $T(I-T)=I$

Comment: @dEmigOd yes you are right. But maybe my incorrect comment already gives sufficient information for OP to work it out.